# Custom Dynamic Loss function: No gradients provided for any variable

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am using an RGB dataset for my  x train and the loss is calculated in a dynamic loss function that gets the distances of pairs  and compares them against the ideal distance dist_train. Here is the model:

```
class MyModel(Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__()
    self.d1 = Dense(3, activation='relu')
    self.flatten = Flatten()
    self.d2 = Dense(3, activation='relu')
    self.d3 = Dense(2)

  def call(self, x):
    x = self.d1(x)
    x = self.flatten(x)
    x = self.d2(x)
    return self.d3(x)

# Create an instance of the model
model = MyModel()

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

train_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='train_loss')
test_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='test_loss')

@tf.function
def train_step(rgb):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        predictions = model(rgb, training=True)
        loss = tf_function(predictions)
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))

    train_loss(loss)
```

Here is the loss function and the tf.function wrapping it:

```
def mahal_loss(output):
  
    mahal = sp.spatial.distance.pdist(output, metric='mahalanobis')
    mahal = sp.spatial.distance.squareform(mahal, force='no', checks=True)

    new_distance = []

    mahal =  np.ma.masked_array(mahal, mask=mahal==0)
    for i in range(len(mahal)):
        pw_dist = mahal[i, indices_train[i]]
        new_distance.append(pw_dist)

    mahal_loss = np.mean((dist_train - new_distance)**2)


    
    return mahal_loss

@tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(None, tf.float32)])
def tf_function(pred):
    y = tf.numpy_function(mahal_loss, [pred], tf.float32) 
    return y
```

Running the model:

```
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    train_loss.reset_states()

    test_loss.reset_states()
    
    for i in x_train:
        train_step(i)

    print(
        f'Epoch {epoch + 1}, '
        f'Loss: {train_loss.result()}, '
        f'Test Loss: {test_loss.result()}, '
     )
```

I believe the reason I am running into problems lies in the dynamic loss function, as I need to calculate the distance between certain pairs to get the results I expect. This means that inside the loss function I have to calculate the mahalanobis distance of each pair to get the ones I will compare against the correct distances. The error I get is the following:

````
    <ipython-input-23-0e975da5cbc2>:15 train_step  *
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
    C:\Anaconda3\envs\colour_env\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py:622 apply_gradients  **
        grads_and_vars = optimizer_utils.filter_empty_gradients(grads_and_vars)
    C:\Anaconda3\envs\colour_env\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizer_v2\utils.py:72 filter_empty_gradients
        raise ValueError("No gradients provided for any variable: %s." %

    ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['my_model/dense/kernel:0', 'my_model/dense/bias:0', 'my_model/dense_1/kernel:0', 'my_model/dense_1/bias:0', 'my_model/dense_2/kernel:0', 'my_model/dense_2/bias:0'].```
````

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the use of `tf.numpy_function`.
Specifically, everything that happens inside the `with tf.GradientTape() as tape` statement has to be differentiable. Because the conversion between `tf.Tensor` and numpy array is not differentiable, `tf.numpy_function` cannot be used for loss computation:

> Since the function takes numpy arrays, you cannot take gradients through a numpy_function. If you require something that is differentiable, please consider using tf.py_function.

(Source: [here in the official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/numpy_function))

So either wrap the loss comutation in `tf.py_function` as this accepts `tf.Tensor`s or consider implementing it in tensorflow. [Here](https://fairyonice.github.io/mahalanobis-tf2.html) is an example for that.